# TV show where an alien starship hovers above the Earth. At first, it seems the aliens are here to offer help. Then it turns out they have a hive mind

Tags: story-identification, tv, alien-invasion

I'm looking for a TV show where a starship hovers above the Earth with an alien race that seems to offer help and new technology.
After a while, it turns out they want to enslave humanity. Some aliens though are on the humans' side. There is an alien queen, like in a bee hive.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, can you describe what the aliens looked like?

Comment: Sounds like any one of several different Doctor Who (2005) episodes.

Answer (score 15):

This mostly fits the plot of the [2009 remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(2009_TV_series)) of the [1983 mini-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1983_miniseries)) "V" (V standing for Visitors) with Morena Baccarin as the Alien queen Anna. Alien ships hover over Earth cities, the visitors promise to share technology, and at first seem to keep word, but it soon turns out that they have sinister plans with humanity. Some aliens disagree with the goal of planetary conquest and help the developing human resistance.

No hive mind, though, but else a reasonable fit. As pointed out in the comment by Jontia, the Queen uses some sort of telepathic influence - the "bliss" - on large groups that somewhat resembles a hive mind (although the number of people/aliens she can control at once is limited).

Decent series, story-wise less good than the original (but then your mileage may vary).

Comment: I think Anna's Bliss comes close enough to Hive Mind for the story-id tag.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be Earth: Final Conflict. The Taelons came in "peace" to help humanity, and were connected to the "Commonality" (hive mindy thingy). I really can't remember much. Worth a look.

Comment: The commonality is a kind of hive mind, but the Taelon have a council rather than a single ruling individual. Fun show though :)